# Фон для игры агарио

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю игру, но столкнулся с проблемой. Есть фон. На фоне я поместил:

```
<div class="ball"></div>
```

И в javascript прописал, что бы фон двигался относительно нашему div`у

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
var coorX = (e.clientX/70);
document.body.style.backgroundPositionX = coorX+"%";
var coorY = (e.clientY/70);
document.body.style.backgroundPositionY = coorY+"%";
}
```

Всё получилось, если бы не одно "НО". Фон движется но моя карта

```
background: url("images/background.png");
```

не даёт фону перемещаться больше 100-150px. Вот пример из моей игры: представим, что область которая обведена синим, это мой экран, а жёлтое, это та часть карты которую не видно если фон не будет двигаться. Так вот, что мне нужно. Как сделать так, что бы фон двигался больше чем размер моего экрана (движение за мышкой onmousemove)
[image: -]

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону графических библиотек и движков, иначе процесс разработки вашей игры вряд ли подойдет к завершению. Рекомендую Pixi.js CAAT.js

```
http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/caat/
http://www.pixijs.com/
http://phaser.io/
```

Есть ещё миллиард других, так же можно из таких движков как Unreal экспортировать в html5